# Determine $s: M_{2x2}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow\ \mathbb{R}^{3}$ such us $ST=Id$ given $T:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\ M_{2x2}(\mathbb{R})$ injective

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, linear-transformations

Determine $T:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\ M_{2x2}(\mathbb{R})$ injective such as $Im(T)$ contains the following vectors

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$

Then, determine $s: M_{2x2}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow\ \mathbb{R}^{3}$ such us $ST=Id$

I've defined $T: \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\\ c\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a+c & b \\ a & b\\ \end{pmatrix} $ that I believe satisfies the requested since $Ker(T)= {0} $ and $dim(Im(T))=dim \mathbb{R}^{3} $

For the second part, I was thinking to  find $s$ as the inverse of the matrix associated to the transformation $T$ since is injective. But I've realized that the $det(T)=0$ i.e. the determinant of the matrix of the transformation is null then isn't invertible, which confuses me since is injective. Does anyone can explain this fact? Does anyone can suggest any other way I could proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since $s$ is a map from a $4$-dimensional vector space to a $3$-dimensional vector space, it cannot be invertible (or for that purpose the inverse of $T$). However, you can demand that the restriction of $S$ to $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ be the inverse. There's of course many ways to achieve that but here is one that undoes the particular $T$ that you picked:
$$ S : \mathrm{Mat}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3, \\ 
       \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix} \mapsto (C, (B+D)/2, A-C)^T.$$

Comment: Then since the matrix associated to T isn't a square matrix can't be invertible. Is this the only case exception of an injective linear map that's satisfies that isn't invertible?

Comment: That's right - neither $S$ nor $T$ are square matrices but you can still take their product. If you take $S*T$ then you get the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix, whereas if you take $T * S$ you get a $4 \times 4$ matrix of rank $3$.

Comment: Put differently, a matrix representing an injective map has to have at least as many rows as columns, and its rank is the maximal possible one - namely the number of its columns. A surjective map is like the "transpose" version of that (such as S in the story above)